# How to prevent smbtree from asking for a password?

Tags: samba

On my Debian system, `smbtree` (as well as all the other relevant samba commands) keeps asking for some sort of passwort for my user account. The command works no matter what password I enter. I don't remember ever setting a password for a `CIFS` share anywhere. I didn't even know those things could be password-protected.

Why is this, and how do I disable the password prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, because for listing shares it doesn't require password. but yet it asks for it. Use `smbtree -N`

Checkout `man smbtree` for more